# Forgefire ammo pouch final upgrade needs a raccoon skin, is this a glitch?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn, horizon-zero-dawn-the-frozen-wilds

This is after completing the Horizon Zero Dawn main quest, and then continuing the game to play The Frozen Wilds DLC.

The Forgefire ammo pouch upgrade #4 requires a raccoon skin, however I've yet to see a raccoon in this portion of the map. I went back to the Nora area of the map, and only see machines now, no animals.

Is this a glitch?  Should the ammo pouch upgrade be asking for a raccoon skin in this DLC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the 'Embrace' area where you start the main game I think that after the events of the main story there are no animals left there. I think this is to emphasize the devastation caused.

All other areas of the main map should still have plenty of animals (although raccoons are one of the rarer animals).

A few of the upgrade quests do take you back to the main game area.